# Generate a message out of cutout magazine characters (interview question)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This problem comes out of the dynamic programming chapter in *The Algorithm Deisgn Manual* by Skiena.

> Give an algorithm to determine whether you can generate a given string by pasting cutouts from a magazine.  You are given a function that will identify the character and its position on the reverse side of the page for any given character position.

I solved this with with backtracking, but since it's in the dynamic programming chapter I think there must be a recurrence I can't figure out.  Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Seems all too straightforward - I must be missing something.  The only 'interesting' part is the talk of 'the reverse side of the page' which seems like a bit of irrelevant misdirection - or not?

Comment: Without the reverse bit, the problem is trivial.  But if I'm understanding it correctly, with reverse cutouts you run into the problem that the first i characters you've matched in your string might have "cut out" critical characters for you to match in the rest of your string.  You'll have to go back and find a different matching set for the first i characters and try again.

Comment: For those who might be having  a hard time understanding the question (I did), basically, you have a bunch of pieces of paper with a single letter on each side. In the original question they came from a magazine, but they could come from anywhere. You then have to determine whether you can arrange those pieces of paper to form some target word. You can only use each piece once, but you can choose what order you want them in and which side you want to use from each piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with maximum bipartite matching.

Each character L of the given string forms the left set. (Note, you repeat the characters if the string has repeated characters).

Each pair of characters (R1,R2) of the magazine forms the right set.

L is connected to (r1,r2) iff L=R1 or L=R2.

Find a maximum matching in the resulting graph. If all left vertices are part of the matching, you have the answer. If not, such a string is not possible.

See [Maximum Bipartite Matchings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_matching#Maximum_bipartite_matchings) for an algorithm.

Not sure if this is optimal though and sorry for not answering exactly as asked.

Comment: With this approach you can form a message with more characters than the magazine :)

Comment: @Tom: No, the size of matching is bounded by the number of nodes in the right set (and the left set), which can never exceed the characters in the magazine. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @Tom: According to the question, given a position you get the character and the character on the reverse. Maybe i misread. In any case, instead of pair, you can have a set of characters.

Comment: @Moron: OK, I think you're right, though I'm still confused by the wording

Comment: @TOm: I agree, the wording is very weird.

Comment: @Moron: This is a really nice solution.  There must be a dynamic programming approach too since it was in that chapter. @Tom: the way I understand it is that one character maps to one character on the reverse side, not multiple characters.

Comment: I see, there's a linear programming algorithm for maximal flow.  That's a complicated interview question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recursive backtracking solution, you may be able to apply [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), which is one way to do dynamic programming.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was thinking about this, but my backtracking solution was a depth first search that didn't ever need to recalculate a previously calculated smaller solution.  I'm sure I must have formulated it poorly.